# how can i run a html page which is a part of cordova project

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

i have latest cordova installed using "command Line"  and android latest setup installed and also eclipse-juno..but m getting an error while opening a html through web browser in eclipse and the error is here:
[image]

please help me guys

Comment: Does it work on emulator(AVD)?

Comment: NO...its only showing the starting page that "Device is Ready"

Comment: Post your code. That will help to get some idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your Eclipse environment as indicated on the Cordova website:

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

Then, you should be able to run your code on the Android emulator provided in the Android SDK.

Comment: i have already done that ...but it doesn't solve my problem..in fact the problem have occurred after applying those stpes